# Regression extensions

Tags: finance, regression, econometrics

I'm trying to find extensions for my regression and obviously would like to use PE, BV and CFO. But I've got monthly data, while all company's fundamentals are semi-annually... Can I deal with it somehow?

Comment: What "regression" are you using??? What data do you have that only exists monthly?

Answer (score 1):

It exists several techniques to deal with mixed-frequency data. I believe **MIxed DAta Sampling** is the best-known.

Eg:

- bridge equation,
- MIxed DAta Sampling (MIDAS) models
- Mixed frequency VARs
- Mixed frequency factor models
- ...

Here is a good document on this topic: [A survey of econometric methods for mixed- frequency data](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3ai4FO0H5T_2cJ%3awww.norges-bank.no/pages/93112/Norges_Bank_Working_Paper_2013_06.pdf%20&hl=es-419&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESiWnBbMTYse4JAyzh8zRTklDNo_go_wWSs1B7wirxJRv-V_bONuFFwfo-LP7EwjgwNEMysPVrpo5fT7kgAGp19bg2IClQiAYhrWAEa5u2uDlpdnOvEXCra2FyKlwSLxlUm08gZw&sig=AHIEtbSKKop8ry6EmhGjTwsaakghe1gdpQ)